# How to disable all scheduled jobs in civicrm.settings.php?

Tags: scheduled-job, civicrm.settings.php

Similar to e.g.:

```
$civicrm_setting['Directory Preferences']['extensionsDir'] = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Louise/git-7/sites/semper-it.local/civicrm/extensions';
```

Can I do something that sets all scheduled jobs to => disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a new feature in the latest 4.7 that allows you to configure your site as non-production, which should do a bunch of things like this.

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/staging-production/

If you're using an older version of CiviCRM, you can manually disable all the jobs with this sql:

`UPDATE civicrm_job SET is_active = 0;`

But you'd want to make sure (manually) that some don't get auto-enabled (e.g. via the managed record feature in an extension).

Ultimately, the safest way to run a non-production site is in some kind of container that doesn't allow outgoing requests/emails.

Comment: Yes - but what about 4.6ers?

Comment: Yeah, that would need a different approach, and I don't think there are any civicrm.settings.php entries that would work either, since those are from 4.7. You'd probably want a little extension to do this, to just run a little sql that disables all the extensions, something like:
`UPDATE civicrm_job SET is_active = 0;`